# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///assets/Upload/Item/214b5d5c-ca86-45f5-bb45-7850559a23bb.jpg

Tags: flutter

```
  ======== Exception caught by image resource service 
 ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
```

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///assets/Upload/Item/214b5d5c-ca86-45f5-
bb45-
7850559a23bb.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2636:9)

#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2565:48)

#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)

#3      NetworkImage.load

(package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)

#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.

```
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:13)
```

...

```
Image provider: NetworkImage("assets/Upload/Item/214b5d5c-ca86-45f5- 
 bb45-  7850559a23bb.jpg",    scale:  1.0)

Image key: NetworkImage("assets/Upload/Item/214b5d5c-ca86-45f5-bb45-
7850559a23bb.jpg", scale:  1.0)
```

Comment: Ask yourself: is `assets/Upload/Item/214b5d5c-ca86-45f5-bb45-7850559a23bb.jpg` a valid URL?

Comment: suggest me what i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong image provider class to provide locally stored images. The proper use-case for `NetworkImage()` class is providing remotely hosted URLs such as hosted in web/storage bucket.

In your case, in order to provide an image locally stored in the assets folder, you need to use `AssetImage()` instead. Please follow the documentation for more details.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html

Comment: Image is stored in an array then I call the array through network image  also another issue is this Exception: Invalid image data

Comment: Unless array items are fully qualified remote host URLs such as `https://example.com/image` `NetworkImage`  provider can not render them. According to provided snippet on your question, you want to render some images from the assets directory of the app. Therefore you need to use `AssetImage` instead of no matter how you have stored the data.

Comment: Unable to load asset: assets/Upload/Item/0d8442aa-a1cc-4716-bb73-7ceee78464fe.jpgWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/Upload/Item/0d8442aa-a1cc-4716-bb73-7ceee78464fe.jpg")

Comment: Have you enabled the assets directory in pubspec.yaml? the assets directory should enable by adding the following lines under flutter: in pubspec.yaml. There would be a commented version available describing how to enable this. 
flutter: 
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/

Comment: Yes its fine but still same issue

Comment: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///